# How to update notification icon in home with Fcm background handler with cubit

Tags: flutter, notifications, background, firebase-cloud-messaging

i want to change a state using cubit when receiving Fcm in background.

i have accessed the conext of the layout where the cubit is provided in the Fcm background handler function to change the state, but the state does not change.